# Getting my AngularJS calls in a bad order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem I am parsing some json files to an html page and the Urls are in another json file: I had a big problem because no error was detected and I was getting an empty page so while debugging using some alerts I discovered that my controller is getting an empty list: 
I should have my calls in the order of my alerts:

```
 alert(tab[i]+ " 1");
 alert(list+ " 2");
 alert(list+ " 3");
```

However I got this order:

```
 alert(tab[i]+ " 1");
 alert(list+ " 3");
 alert(list+ " 2");
```

Here's my code

```js
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {        
  function getLists() {
    $http.get('url').success(function(data) { 
      return data;

      var tab = [];
      for (i = 0; i < (data).length; i++) {
        tab.push(data[i]);
      }
    
      var list = [];
      for(i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
        alert(tab[i]+ " 1");
        
        $http.get(tab[i]).then(function(res) {
          list.push(res.data);
          alert(list+ " 2");
        });
        
        alert(list+" 3");
      }
      
      return list;
    })
  }

  return {
    getLists: getLists
  };
])};
```

I use only AngularJS not Ajax nor jQuery.
What should I do?

Comment: You're using `$http.get` which is async.

Comment: actually you're using ajax

Comment: Try using angular promises.

Comment: $http is an asynchronous wrapper for the XMLHTTPRequest (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Also, angular uses jQuery; it has jqLite built in.

Comment: Use angular promise `$q.all`  because you have got multiple async call. Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. Provide the structure of the JSON for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my question well it was too simple I just had to declare list in the getLists function and add the return list outside the first http.get:

```js
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {        
  function getLists() {
    var list = [];
    $http.get('url').success(function(data) { 
      return data;

      var tab = [];
      for (i = 0; i < (data).length; i++) {
        tab.push(data[i]);
      }
    
      
      for(i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
        alert(tab[i]+ " 1");
        
        $http.get(tab[i]).then(function(res) {
          list.push(res.data);
          alert(list+ " 2");
        });
        
        alert(list+" 3");
      }
      
    
    })
      return list;
  }

  return {
    getLists: getLists
  };
])};
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're attempting to make async requests in a for loop, the return order is completely inconsistent due to the nature of asynchronous requests. You must ensure the return order with something like [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), which allows you to resolve promises in order.

```
app.factory('listsFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  function getLists() {
    return $http.get('url').success(function(tabs) {
      return $q.all(tabs.map(function(tab) {
        return $http.get(tab)
          .then(function(res) {
            return res.data;
          });
      }));
    })
  }

  return {
    getLists: getLists
  };
}]);
```

Then, to use `getLists` like so:

```
app.controller('myController', ['listsFactory', function(listsFactory) {
  listsFactory.getLists().then(function(lists) {
    // do something with lists
    // $scope.something = lists;
  });
}]);
```

To break it down a bit: it seems that your first loop for setting tabs is redundant since the callback arg contains the data you want (unless I'm missing something). So just name the arg `tabs`, then pass a new array of promises to `$q.all` and return that. When `getLists` is invoked, it will return a promise with an array of containing the values of each promise, in order.

To expound on the `success` callback arg:

```
$http.get('url').success(function(data) {
  var tab = [];
  for (i = 0; i < (data).length; i++) {
   tab.push(data[i]);
  }
...
```

What you're doing here is unnecessary since you're effectively cloning `data` so that it's a new array, with the same values, but named `tabs` instead. You can avoid this by naming the `success` callbacks argument `tabs`. This will contain the **same exact** data as your version and also reduces redundancy.

Comment: Thank you I got some appreared data and now I have this data.map is not a function

Comment: Can you update your question with the result of `console.log(data)`, please?

Comment: well I got nothing  in the console :/

Comment: That means your request to your initial get request is returning nothing. Could you update the question with your latest code?

Comment: Are you _actually_ requesting the url `'url'`? Or have you redacted the actual URL that you were originally using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116201/discussion-between-seth-and-nour-nour).

Comment: You're unable to join the chat? No worries then... we can communicate in the comments. But could you answer my question regarding the `$http.get`'s URL?

Comment: Also, your updated code still has for loops... you must remove them so that it matches my answer or it will not work.

Comment: I am using the url 'url' . if i remvoe the loops, how would I push the data to list

Comment: you need to use a valid URL. is `url` an actual URL? The code that i've provided pushes all tabs to a list and returns them as a promise.

Comment: I suspect you've altered my answer then as this will work. I've used it many times before with the same requirement that you have in your question. It has served me well with no issues. Could you update your question again with your latest working example?

Comment: I found the solution for my question well it was too simple I just had to declare list in the getLists function and add the return list outside the first http.get thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about all the issues, due to your formatting, but it seems that the first line of your anonymous success handler returns the data and then you proceed to the for loop which probably never gets executed, since you returned a value from that function.

Comment: no, you never get to your loop because of the "return data;" statement on line 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(tab[i]+ " 1");
alert(list+ " 3");
alert(list+ " 2");
```

You are getting order in following order because `alert(list + " 2")` in within a `$http` call back function which is async. So it is not guaranteed when you call back function will be called.

However `alert(list + " 3")` will be executed as soon as for loop is completed. i.e.  Async calls in for loop is made but not called back the function.

That is the reason you are getting `alert(list + " 3")` before `alert(list + " 2")`.

```
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {        
  function getLists() {
    $http.get('url').success(function(data) { 
      return data;

      var tab = [];
      for (i = 0; i < (data).length; i++) {
        tab.push(data[i]);
      }
      var list = [];
      var promises = [];
      for(i=0; i < tab.length; i++){        
        promises.push($http.get(tab[i]));        
      }

      $q.all(promises).then(function(data) {        
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
          this.push(value);
          alert(list + " 2");
        }, list);
        alert(list + " 3");
      });
      return list;
    })
  }

  return {
      getLists: getLists
  };
])};
```

Comment: Your example is returning `data` early.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad..  In fact. I copied the code from main question and modified to use $q.all